# .Autofilter not working in the code

Tags: excel, vba

This code is not working

```
ActiveSheet.Select
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
With ActiveSheet

        .AutoFilterMode = False

        .Range("A1:D1").AutoFilter

End With
```

Give an error "Method of range class Failed"

Comment: Make sure the active sheet is not a Chart.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working without any error on my system. Few instances of users experiences are mentioned here to explore possible causes of malfunctioning on your system.

A). when you change sheets too often in VBA and get an "Activate Method Of Range Class Failed" or a "Select Method Of Range Class Failed" etc, simply retype the sheets command before it

for example :

Sheets("Work1").Select
Range("A1:D1").Select

OR

Sheets(Work1").Range("A1:D1").Select

This code in VBA, if used too often or the mentioned sheet is not the currently selected sheet in a Sub, will cause errors, and to correct this, simply retype. The macro should be activated when the relevant sheet is the active one.

B) When one proceeds further following situations can also give error 1004.

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
Sheets("Sheet3").AutoFilterMode = False 
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("d1:d6000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ComboBox1.Value, visibledropdown:=False 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

OR
VB:
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
Sheets("Sheet3").AutoFilterMode = False 
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:D6000").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=ComboBox1.Value, visibledropdown:=False 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

IN the first one, the range has only one column, and so you cannot specify a field as 4
In the second one, the range has 4 columns, ie, from A to D, and here you can specify any field from 1 to 4

C)    From MSDN 
The destination must include the source range. Specifiying just the column name means that you want to fill every row in that column which is unlikely to be the desired behvaiour.

HTH